Will damage to the subfloor from carpet tack strip be a problem with laminate flooring?
I'm removing my old carpet and having laminate flooring laid.
Upon removing the old carpet grippers, the nails holding them in place have slightly damaged the base floor covering all along, but only about an inch in. Will I still be able to go ahead and have the laminate laid anyway?

What is "the base floor covering"? Do you mean the plywood or OSB subfloor?

You should not have any issues unless the new flooring is very thin.
A thin vinyl that is glued down may show some of the nail "scars'. However any good laminate or LVP is thick enough to not be affected by some divots close to the walls.
A "rule of thumb" I use is an imperfection should be no thicker than a nickel and the flooring should be a minimum of 5.5mm thick.
